# Event target not working in my blazor project

Tags: javascript, blazor

Im trying to click an element and get the offsetTop position. Im trying to do this with this javascript code:

```
window.ShowAlert = function myFunction(event) {   
    console.log("Hello World.");
    alert(event.target.offsetTop);
}
```

This code is inside a folder in my wwwroot and in my Index.razor I have this code:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div>
    <Member OnClick="MemberFunction" />
</div>

@code {
    void MemberFunction()
    {
        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ShowAlert");
    }
}
```

When I run this the console log appears as expected but the alert doesn't, and I tried to change the alert to appear "Hello World" and works fine, the problem is the `event.target`. 
Why the alert with the offsetTop position is not working?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You aren't passing anything in for event when you call your function.  So event would be null in myFunction.

Comment: @TonyAbrams Oh ok, so how could I pass the object clicked?

Comment: Looking over the docs, you just pass it in to the Invoke Async Method.  I would just pass in the offset, but that's me. EX: jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ShowAlert", offsetTop);

Comment: Docs > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I can't pass the offsetTop because its a javascript property and give me an error, what I need to pass there is the object that I clicked. Im looking to the docs trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the elementRef to the javascript method using @ref:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div>
    <Member @onclick="MemberFunction" @ref="memberRef"/>
</div>

@code {

    private ElementReference memberRef;
    void MemberFunction()
    {
        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ShowAlert", memberRef);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You will need to modify the javascript:

```
window.ShowAlert = function myFunction(element) {   
    console.log("Hello World.");
    alert(element.offsetTop);
}
```

**NOTE**

I changed OnClick to @onclick.

You can see a demo on BlazorFiddle -> https://blazorfiddle.com/s/61o1g7ef

Comment: Well the alert appears me but appears me undefined. What can be the issue now? If I put just the element, it gives me the value of it.

Comment: So offsetTop is undefined?

Comment: Ok I found the issue in my Member Im doing an onClick event passing a parameter and the element is the parameter that Im passing. Thats why I can't get the position of it.

Comment: Check my update, the code I ran gives the alert with a position.

Comment: Yeah it's my bad cause I didn't noticed before this and now I need to think all over again how to do it. Basically my element is a parameter of a Member List and so on I can't get the position of it, only the value of it. In your case it's working cause your element reference is to the Member component and not to one parameter of it as me. It was totally my bad. Thank you for your attention and help. I appreciate it.
The part of code that Im telling you its the issue is this:
`@onclick="@(() => OnClick.InvokeAsync(member.MemberFamilyName))`

Comment: I have this in my Member so the element reference is for my member.MemberFamilyName and not for the Member Component,